# Restkit fails when I update architecture to arm64

Tags: ios, objective-c, 64-bit, restkit

When I update my project architecture to 64 bit these issues appear. My deployment target is 7.1.

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "OBJC_CLASS$RKClient",
>   referenced from: objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o objc-class-ref in
>   SSRSuggestion.o "_OBJC_CLASS$RKObjectManager", referenced from:
>   objc-class-ref in CinemaDetails-3BD8C6BC69EF1F23.o objc-class-ref in
>   AppDelegate.o objc-class-ref in HomeScreen.o objc-class-ref in
>   MovieDetails.o objc-class-ref in CinemaFilter-46E8309ACAC69139.o
>   objc-class-ref in FilterView.o "_OBJC_CLASS$RKObjectMapping",
>   referenced from: objc-class-ref in Cinema.o objc-class-ref in Movie.o
>   objc-class-ref in Filter.o objc-class-ref in AppInfoModel.o
>   "_OBJC_CLASS$RKParserRegistry", referenced from: objc-class-ref in
>   SSRSuggestion.o "_OBJC_CLASS$RKRequestQueue", referenced from:
>   objc-class-ref in CinemaDetails-3BD8C6BC69EF1F23.o objc-class-ref in
>   AppDelegate.o objc-class-ref in MovieDetails.o
>   "_OBJC_CLASS$_RKRequestSerialization", referenced from: objc-class-ref
>   in SSRSuggestion.o "_RKMIMETypeJSON", referenced from: -[SSRSuggestion
>   send_btn_pressed:] in SSRSuggestion.o ld: symbol(s) not found for
>   architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code
>   1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Describe how you added RestKit to your project and what version it is

Comment: I added restkit into project using pods .

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is gigantically ugly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you have an old version of `RestKit`. Easiest way probably is to use **CocoaPods**. Open terminal, type:

```
$ sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Then go to your project folder in terminal and type:

```
$ pod init
```

Open `.podfile` and insert this line:

```
pod 'RestKit', '~> 0.24'
```

Save and quit the file. In terminal write:

```
$ pod install
```

From this time you should use `.xcwrokspace` instead of `.xcproj`. You should also remove old version of `RestKit`.

---

Another option is to use **git submodules** or **hg subrepos**. I won't type tutorial how to do it here, as it's too much to write, cocoapods are easier for someone new.

---

Another option is to download and add to your project newer RestKit version "from hand" - drag & drop. I **don't recommend** this way, as you never know which version you're using and you can't see that there are new updates to used frameworks (what obviously often fixes bugs).

Comment: Hi Vive, Thanks a lot for your reply I changed the restkit version , I install pods again and I still have the same errors .

Comment: Did you perform Product->Clean or delete derived data..? Maybe something was cached..?

Comment: installed or updated, did the pod log show it updating?

Comment: @Wain If @Nada changed the version to explict 0.24+ (as I wrote above) and has old version installed previously, both `pod install` and `pod update` should bump `RestKit`.

Comment: yes I updated to 0.24 , it successfully updated , but I still have the same errors

Comment: @NadaGamal I would have to check your screen to see what's happening and help you (as girls should keep together in mostly male IT world :P). After debugging we'd post here what was wrong. However I have no idea how to give you and only you credentials to contact with me. Maybe enter http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15038/ios-developer-family?