# I need to integrate 64 bit iOS sales force mobile SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, sdk, salesforce

I need to integrate 64 bit iOS sales force mobile SDK.I am getting the following error when running on 64 bit.

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L"/Users/bizimpact/Documents/Nanda/Projects/Lenspal backup/LespalFiles/EyePal _ME(Arabic)/EyePal/Classes/Support/ThirdParty/TestFlight"'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L"/Users/bizimpact/Documents/Nanda/Projects/Lenspal backup/LespalFiles/EyePal _ME(Arabic)/EyePal/Classes/Support/ThirdParty/Salesforce/dependencies/openssl"'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L"/Users/bizimpact/Documents/Nanda/Projects/Lenspal backup/LespalFiles/EyePal _ME(Arabic)/EyePal/Classes/Support/ThirdParty/Salesforce/dependencies/RestKit"'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L"/Users/bizimpact/Documents/Nanda/Projects/Lenspal backup/LespalFiles/EyePal _ME(Arabic)/EyePal/Classes/Support/ThirdParty/Salesforce/dependencies/SalesforceCommonUtils/Libraries"'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L"/Users/bizimpact/Documents/Nanda/Projects/Lenspal backup/LespalFiles/EyePal _ME(Arabic)/EyePal/Classes/Support/ThirdParty/Salesforce/dependencies/SalesforceOAuth/Libraries"'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L"/Users/bizimpact/Documents/Nanda/Projects/Lenspal backup/LespalFiles/EyePal _ME(Arabic)/EyePal/Classes/Support/ThirdParty/Salesforce/dependencies/SalesforceSDK"'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L"/Users/bizimpact/Documents/Nanda/Projects/Lenspal backup/LespalFiles/EyePal _ME(Arabic)/EyePal/Classes/Support/ThirdParty/Salesforce/dependencies/sqlcipher"'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L"/Users/bizimpact/Documents/Nanda/Projects/Lenspal backup/LespalFiles/EyePal _ME(Arabic)/EyePal/Classes/Support/ThirdParty/GoogleAnalytics"'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L"/Users/bizimpact/Documents/Nanda/Projects/Lenspal backup/LespalFiles/EyePal _ME(Arabic)/EyePal/TestFlightSDK1.2.4"'
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you don't have all the sources. There are a few options:

1. Given folders do not exists on your HDD (maybe you use submodules and didn't update them?)
2. You have wrong reference in header paths in your project configuration.

What does this question has in common with 64bit? This is probably happening the same when you compile for 32bit, isn't it?

-- edit --

Looking at comments below maybe it will be handy for you to use some dependency manager. Here I wrote about few available: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30913633/849616 and how to use them as well as why 'attaching' files to project is always worst solution.

Comment: I need 64bit ios salesforce SDK framework's.To proceed further.I have searched so many way to get the framework's.but there is no solution.Could any one help me.

Comment: Then add in your podfile pod 'SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS'. Or download & attach newest version. You're missing files.

Comment: That one also tried.am getting the files only,not an framework's from podfile.

Comment: Integrating files with your project can be difficult if you're doing it for the first time, and I suspect that's a problem here. Adding the files only is worst method available as you're never going to update and patch bugs from previous versions of used frameworks. You should use either git submodules or simply cocoapods to keep track of version you're using and be able to quickly update the version. Be a good programmer from the beginning, don't just try to "make things work" without quality :)

Comment: I have already using 32bit support salesforce sdk framework's and supporting file in my project.it has working fine,now update it to 64bit architecture,so am looking the 64bit support salesforce sdk framework's.

Comment: @Nanda I've checked it (although your error says that there are no files NOT that there is no support for 64bit) and imported SalesForce SDK version 3.2 via pod 'SalesforceMobileSDK-iOS', '~> 3.2'. Everything works fine on 64bits. What version of Salesforce are you using? This discussion is without sense as you're not even trying to fix your problem and try the advise.